# jQuery to add item from one listbox to another and remove it to the same original position

Tags: jquery, list

I have 2 listboxes and a button to add items from #list1 to #list2.

I also have a button to remove item from #list2 and add it again to #list1. But, when I remove the selected item, it goes to the end of the #list1.

Is there a way to make this removed item return to its original position?

Thanks!!

Comment: Looks like you double submitted this question. You should delete one.

Comment: Even if he doesn't, the community will vote to close one of them.  There's already two votes to close this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many items, going back to the original position will be tricky unless you store the original position relative to all other items (since you might remove other items from #list1).

To keep things simple you could instead provide an **undo button** that restored the most recently-moved item to its original position, by remembering either the previous or next elements in the list.

Store:

1. $(item).prev() and $(item).next() of the most recently-moved item, and
2. the removed item as removedItem.

Then depending on whether there's a prev() or after() defined for the original item, use something like:

```
$($(item).prev()).after(removedItem);
```

to restore the most recently-moved item to its original position.

Answer (score 1):

I found a really good tutorial that covers this in video format, so instead of trying to debug your code I will point you to the vid!

I hope it helps :D

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-day-5/

Comment: I watched the video, but it's not exacly what I'm looking for... but, thanks anyway! :-)